# Android - javax.mail.Authenticator does not send email any longer?

Tags: java, android, email

I am using GMail in an application I made to send emails with attached files in them. The way I did it is that my app would automatically compose the message, attach an attachment, and send it to the recipients without having to open the Mail application.

The application is currently in production already and just this morning, I found out that I wasn't able to send emails any longer. At first I thought it that the devices did not have internet connection, or that the password was changed, but both of these weren't true and I checked the logcat and I am getting this error:

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 553 5.1.2 The address specified is not a valid RFC-5321 address. si10sm4645040pab.15 - gsmtp
```

Upon researching the problem, I found out that Google released an update between Oct 31 and Nov 1, and it somehow affected this (as well as Office Outlook, Thunderbird, and other mailing application). However, I couldn't figure out what they had changed (if it was the ports) or something else. Here is my code:

This the `Mail.java` class that I am using:

```
public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator { 
    private String _user; 
    private String _pass; 

    private String[] _to; 
    private String _from; 

    private String _port; 
    private String _sport; 

    private String _host; 

    private String _subject; 
    private String _body; 

    private boolean _auth; 

    private boolean _debuggable; 

    private Multipart _multipart; 


    public Mail() { 
        _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server 
        _port = "465"; // 465 -- default smtp port
        _sport = "465"; // 465 -- default socketfactory port

        _user = ""; // username 
        _pass = ""; // password 
        _from = ""; // email sent from 
        _subject = ""; // email subject 
        _body = ""; // email body 

        _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
        _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

        _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

        // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the
        // multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.
        MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
        mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
        mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
        mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
        mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
        mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
        CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
    } 

    public Mail(String user, String pass) { 
        this(); 

        _user = user; 
        _pass = pass; 
    } 

    public boolean send() throws Exception { 
        Properties props = _setProperties(); 

        if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("")
                && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 

            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 

            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

            InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
            for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
                addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
            } 
            msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

            msg.setSubject(_subject); 
            msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 

            // setup message body 
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
            messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
            _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

            // Put parts in message 
            msg.setContent(_multipart); 

            // send email 
            Transport.send(msg); 

            return true; 
        } else { 
            return false; 
        } 
    } 

    public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);        
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));

        // Truncating the full file path to just filename
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^/]*$");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(filename);

        if (m.find()){          
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(m.group());
        }
        else{ 
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
        }

        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    }


    @Override 
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
        return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
    } 

    private Properties _setProperties() { 
        Properties props = new Properties(); 

        props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 

        if(_debuggable) { 
            props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
        } 

        if(_auth) { 
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
        } 

        props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 

        return props; 
    } 

    // the getters and setters here
}
```

And I use this class as such in an activity:

```
private boolean sendEmail(String attachmentFilePath, String subject){

    Mail m = new Mail("sender.email@gmail.com", "passwordHere");
    String[] toArr = {"destination@yahoo.com"};

    m.set_to(toArr); 

    //include time here
    m.set_from("sender");
    m.set_subject(subject);
    m.setBody("Please check the attached file.");

    try { 
        m.addAttachment(attachmentFilePath); 
        if(m.send()) { 

            File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/csv", "");

            File original = new File(attachmentFilePath);

            String baseFilename = original.getName().toString().replace(".csv", "");
            File to = new File(exportDir, baseFilename +  " (sent).csv");
            original.renameTo(to);

        }
        else { 
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        } 
    }
    catch(Exception e) { 
        //Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e);
        return false;
    } 
    return true;
}
```

However, I don't seem to be able to send the email since I get the error:

```
11-05 10:58:56.244    7672-7692/com.agict.marswin E/MailApp﹕ Could not send email
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 553 5.1.2 The address specified is not a valid RFC-5321 address. qc16sm4604799pab.47 - gsmtp
```

And I'm not quite sure what happened here. It does not seem like the ports were changed and I don't have any errors or typographical errors in the email address that I'm using to send and the addresses I am sending to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also facing similar issue. Try adding the @gmail.com to your senders email address. Worked for me.